# Execute query using daily timestamp (mysql event)

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I was trying to find a way for give users a daily "point" per online day.

So my plan was setup a MySQL event to run this query:

```
UPDATE users SET points=points+1 WHERE timestamp > "X"
```

(Where X is the `timestamp` running since the 12.01AM of the current day).
The problem is that I didn't find any way to change daily `timestamp` (or the X in query) automatically. There is anyway to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [date_format function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). You can use it this way:

```
mysql> select date_format(now(), "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00");
+-----------------------------------------+
| date_format(now(), "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00") |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2016-04-25 00:00:00                     |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Or, if you want minute 1, as per your example:

```
mysql> select date_format(now(), "%Y-%m-%d 00:01:00");
+-----------------------------------------+
| date_format(now(), "%Y-%m-%d 00:01:00") |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2016-04-25 00:01:00                     |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation would be to do the date math as follows

## SINCE MIDNIGHT (12:00 AM)

```
UPDATE users SET points=points+1 WHERE timestamp > (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 SECOND);
```

## SINCE 12:01 AM

```
UPDATE users SET points=points+1 WHERE timestamp > (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
```

Since you asked about a MySQL Event, you can do the same thing

Something like this

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS ev $$
CREATE EVENT ev
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 SECOND + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE DO
BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET points=points+1
    WHERE timestamp >= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 SECOND - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND   timestamp <  (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 SECOND);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This will setup the event midnight tonight, and the query will increment `points` for all records whose timestamp was yesterday.

Keep in mind these expressions

- `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 SECOND - INTERVAL 1 DAY` is midnight yesterday
- `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 SECOND` is midnight today
- `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 SECOND + INTERVAL 1 DAY` is midnight tomorrow

**One more thing... please make sure `timestamp` is indexed**

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: `+ INTERVAL 0 SECOND` could be omitted with changing the result; correct?